# How do i pass the text inside a html tag to another page and update that page with the text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables, parameter-passing

To further explain,

I have text that says "Cart(0)" every time someone clicks a button the number increments when I click "Cart" I want it to take me to a new page while sending the text "Cart(1)" (say someone added one item). I want it to show Cart(1) on the next page and pass that value over.

```
    <li><a id="cart" href="cart.html">Cart</a></li>
```

I have a javascript file that increments and updates that text like so:

```
     function addToCart(){
         ++cartcount;
         document.getElementById("cart").innerHTML = "Cart("+cartcount+")";
     }
```

Now when I click the cart it should take me to another page and still have whatever number beside the cart and store the number in a variable that I can use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I saw many questions but they were hard to understand in my context.

Comment: When you use the client side library as `jquery`, `javascript`, when you change the page it will lose data, Of course you can use `localstorage` to share cart value to another pages, but if you ask me it's not good for a store which keep all item params as `name`, `price` or etc, you can save just the item `id` in your `localstorage` and then get it from `api` in another page.

Comment: @maher theres no way i get the text from the html tag then send it through the URL and the parse it on the other end on Window load?

Comment: why you should do that it's completely wrong way "sending text by URL" you have to change your model, use `localStorage` please it's much better

Comment: @maher its just that i never used it before. i will look into it for now thank you

Comment: i find this tutorial, read it [HTML5 Local Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp), this sample some how related to your question